# Dimension (width, heigth, length) in woocoommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

In WooCommerce I would like to display dimension (L,W,H) in shop page and single products page as shown below in picture and tried few plugins. But it display only in sidebar not as my requirement (it's like searching products when we change dimension number new products is displayed according to value input that's the complicated part for me)

Dimension:

[image: dimension]

I have attached link of website which feature I want as below:

- Shop page dimension: [shop page link](https://www.selectblindscanada.ca/sheer-shades/)
- Second link single products page: [single-products link](https://www.selectblindscanada.ca/sheer-shades/2-value-light-filtering-sheer-shades.html)

Comment: isnt there any one who could help me ??????